# The rules for Bamboozle

Tags: untagged

I have this peg board game called Bamboozle.  There is a deck of cards from zero to 99 to match the holes in the board.  The object of the game was to get five in a row, and when you held a card in your hand you were only allowed to play it and place your peg equal to or higher than the card played.

But for the life of me, I can't remember how many cards you played with and what the rules were.  Can anybody help?  [image]

Answer (score 3):

This game has been produced over the years in a number of very slightly different versions, originally stemming from a sociological study done in the 1960s; so while I haven't been able to find the rules for this version explicitly, an almost identical version was sold under the name "**Poo-Ka-Boo**", which helpfully has the rules printed on the back of the box.

[image: Poo-Ka-Boo]

For a slightly different version, **[5ive Straight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgeS2.jpg)** (aka **The Game of 99!**) is still produced.

Comment: Thank you KMR  I was leaning towards that end, but now I know for sure.  Some of the cards were destroyed from playing, and as a result, one day I found another set in a garage sale and managed to use some cards from each deck to play again.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @MikeD - if you just need a deck of cards from 1-100 (or 1-99?), then you could buy 6Nimmt, "The Mind", or "The Game" (I would vote for The Mind, as it's also one of my favorite games to play without pegs...)